# Why does Chrome cause very high GPU load in full screen?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, video, gpu

My operating system is Ubuntu 15.04.
Since a few weeks I have an annoying problem with google chrome. Whenever I'm switching to full screen mode - be it a video, a flash application or anything else - the GPU load is going through the roof.

E.g. for Netflix the GPU load is at about 12-14% when running in a maxed window. When switching to full screen it goes up to over 90% and the video playback becomes very choppy. The same happens when turning any flash application into full screen. Since Netflix does not rely on flash disabling PepperFlash is not going to fix this.

This whole mess becomes even stranger when I'm starting Windows in VirtualBox. Even though there is the additional load for the VM layer videos play fluidly when switching the VM and then the video to full screen.

I've being googling for some time now to find a fix but so far had no luck. Any pointers?

Comment: does it happen when you use another browser like Firefox?

Comment: I cannot watch Netflix in Firefox. Regarding Flash I will give it a try now.

Comment: Fullscreen flash videos run smooth in firefox. Seems to be yet another Chrome problem.

Comment: And it works fine in Incognito Mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, by sheer dumb luck I stumbled upon a solution that worked for me like a charm:

When browsing about://gpu I saw that gpu rasterization was turned off. I opened about://flags and changed the setting **Enable GPU rasterization** from *Default* to *Enable*. And now it works! I've been on this for more then two weeks ...

After sending my laptop to sleep (suspend to RAM, that is) and waking it up it stopped working again. I additionally set **Enable display list 2D canvas** to *Enable*, restarted chrome, and it worked once more. Something is truly messed up here. Never the less

Comment: Wow.. why aren't these options default ? Thanks !

Comment: I've also noticed that Google Chrome GPU process will have problems if you have lots of windows open even though none of those render actively. For example, I have currently 58 Chrome windows open with varying sizes (mostly near 1500x1350 pixels) and unless I minimize many enough windows, the GPU process often gets laggy. I have intel HD4000 GPU which is pretty old so the problem may be *less visible* with faster GPUs but the problem still exists. Minimizing an existing Chrome window seems to release GPU resources for that window.